# Accents in math mode in latex

Tags: accents

I am getting an error when I type:

```
$\~{c}_{it+1}} = c_{it+1}$
```

The error says:

```
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ... composite future consumption good $\~{c}
```

How I can modify the code so I use the accent above `c_{it+1}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want
`$\tilde{c}_{it+1}} = c_{it+1}$`.

Some accents have mathematical meaning, hence the warnings or errors.